# How to limite access to database based on ID

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a team of three people with IDs 1-2-3
They report to me the number of articles they produced daily via an app with a database they upload on google drive or dropbox
so the table has three columns : DATE ID and Number
For example when person with ID=1 opens the app on his device only his inputs should be accessible (to view and edit)
But on my device i can see all the data

Answer (score 0):

You can pass as parameter the user id in api Rest Call and make Sql request filtered by this ID, like that you get only result for this id

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on how you write both the android code and the sql code. 
From the sql perspective, in the editors side select all as usual and display in text view for those that he has to view and in editview the ones that he has to edit.
After insert the information into the database.

At the viewers side select as usual and display info in textview or any other widget of your choice.
I cannot actually say much because its really broad. Contact me if you need more specific solutions to your peculiar problem.